# ADOtable cells update

Tags: ado, editbox

Hi here is my problem:

I have EditBox which shows some variable. on the same form I have a ComboBox. Both are bound to an ADOTable, however when I click and change ComboBox..the textBox goes blank. How can I update the record without using Post once I show the variable in the editbox..
Hope that makes sense.

s

Answer (score 0):

Problem is solved. the issue is that the editbox was bound to the database and I was trying to assign value to it..instead I just updated the cell database directly.